# How to get all Identifers after filtering a Dojo Grid

Tags: dojo, grid, xpages

I'm using a dojo enhanced grid with a ItemFileWriteStore and the filter plugin.

```
dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");

dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.Filter");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.exporter.CSVWriter");

dojo.ready(function(){
/*set up data store*/
var data = {
  identifier: 'id',
  items: []
};

var structure = [{
cells:[
{field: "id", datatype: "string", autoComplete: true },
{field: "pecla_ID", datatype: "string", autoComplete: true }

}];


var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({ url: "xGetAllClaims.xsp"});

/*set up layout*/
var layout = [[
    {'name': 'Claim Running No.', 'field': 'pecla_ID', datatype: "string", autoComplete: true, 'width': '138px'},
    {'name': 'Internal No.', 'field': 'pecla_InternalID', 'width': '138px', filterable: false}


]];

/*create a new grid:*/
var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    store: store,
    structure: layout,
    rowSelector: '20px',
    plugins: {
     exporter: true,
        filter: {
            // Show the closeFilterbarButton at the filter bar

            // Set the maximum rule count to 5
            ruleCount: 5,
            structure:structure,
            // Set the name of the items
            itemsName: "id"
        }
    }},
  document.createElement('div')
  );

/*append the new grid to the div*/
dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

/*Call startup() to render the grid*/
grid.startup();


grid.on("RowDblClick", function(evt){
var idx = evt.rowIndex,
    rowData = grid.getItem(idx);
// The rowData is returned in an object, last is the last name, first is the first name
window.open(rowData.notesurl,"_self")

}, true);

});
```

Now to my problem: I want to export the data to Excel
I have tryed to use the export plugin to export to CSV an afterwards to Excel by an XAgent 
but when the CSV Data gehts to big (about 14000 rows) I got an error fron the Server (Domino 8.5.3 FP6)
(Invalid Post Request Exception)

hear is my Code:

```
 dijit.byId("grid").exportGrid("csv",{
            writerArgs: {
                    separator: ";"
                    }
            }, function(str){
                    var form = document.createElement('form');
                    dojo.attr(form, 'method', 'POST');
                    document.body.appendChild(form);

                    dojo.io.iframe.send({
                            url: "xExportToExcel.xsp",
                            form: form,
                            method: "POST",
                            content: {exp: str},
                            timeout: 900000

                    });
                    document.body.removeChild(form);

                    }
            );
```

Has anyone an idea how to get the identifers from the filtered rows to decrease the amount of data?

Comment: Somehow I can't really 'get' your question. It does not make sense to me. Why would you fetch data from the server to the browser, then let the brower (grid) use an CSV exporter to post this data to another Xpage to create an Excel export? Isn't it possible to use some 'arguments' to call your 'xExportToExcel.xsp' Xpage and do all the work serverside? (e.g. get the view,read out data and do the export thing) I think that would save you a lot of work (and this problem!)

Comment: This is only an example what I try to do. and I have tryed to use the Export plugin but i don't need to. My Idea was to get the identifers of the entries which are shown in the grid after and before filtering.